# Optimal parenthesis for matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

The statement goes this way (this scenario occurs while choosing which of all matrix pairs to be parenthesized for optimal matrix multiplication)

`p(n) = Summation of P(k)P(k-n)` is `Ω(2^n)` for `k = 1` to `n - 1` and for `n> = 2`.

`p(n)` is the number of combinations of alternate parenthesis.

Say `p(3) = A1(A2*A3)` or `(A1*A2)A3` or `(A1*A2*A3)`.

`k`: split value.

`n`: number of matrices.

I solved this equation using recursion.

Lets say I have four matrices `A1,A2,A3,A4`.

Lets say `k = 2` and we have `n = 4`.

`p(4) = p(1)p(3) + p(2)p(2)`

Solving recursively for `p(3)` and `p(2)` we get:

`p(4) = p(1)p(3) + p(2)p(2) + p(1)p(1)p(2) + p(1)p(2)p(1) + p(1)p(1)p(1)p(1)`.

What it implies, is that we can parenthesize `A1A2A3A4` in the following ways:

`p(4) = A1(A2A3A4)` or `(A1A2)(A3A4)` or `(A1)(A2)(A3A4)` or `(A1)(A2A3)(A4)` or `(A1)(A2)(A3)(A4)`.

My question is:

if for `n = 3` `p(n) = 3` and for `n = 4` `p(n) = 5`

then how come `p(n) = summation of p(k)p(n-k)` is  `Ω(2^n)`?

Comment: please do care downvoting

Comment: Why dont you do it for more number of ns, say n=10, n=1000, n=1000000 ? You will probably see why the complexity makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`p(n)` is catalan number = `(2n choose n)/(n+1)` and that is `Theta(4^n/n sqrt(n))` (using Stirling's formula) and so is `Omega(2^n)`.

You cannot determined whether a function is `Omega(2^n)` by examining just two values!

Since the bound you are seeking is so weak as compared to the actual theta value, there is probably a simpler proof.